Discord.py how to include the person who deleted
So i just made a event both for on_message_delete and on_message_edit
second one works as intended but for first one, i want to make it like Quark Logger; if message deleted by author, no one will mentioned and when message deleted by someone else, it'll add a field to embed that includes the person who did the action.
here's my approach:
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message_delete(self, message : discord.Message):
     async for entry in message.guild.audit_logs(limit=1,action=discord.AuditLogAction.message_delete):
          deletedBy = entry.user
          logtime = entry.created_at.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
          lcltime = datetime.datetime.now(timezone("UTC")).strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
          if logtime == lcltime and deletedBy != message.author: not_self_delete = True
          else: self_delete = False
     if message.channel.type != discord.ChannelType.private:
          if hasattr(message.author, "guild") and message.guild.id == IEEM:
               channel1=self.bot.get_channel(my_log_chan)
               channel2=self.bot.get_channel(another_log_chan_in_diff_server) 
               embed=discord.Embed(title=f"{message.author.name} deleted a message.", description=f"Content: {message.content} \n Channel: {message.channel.mention}", color=0xFF5733)
               embed.set_author(name=self.bot.user.name, icon_url=self.bot.user.display_avatar)
               if not_self_delete: embed.set_footer(text=f"Message deleted at: {localtime} \nMessage deleted by: {deleter.name}")
               else: embed.set_footer(text=f"Message deleted at: {localtime}")
               attachmentFiles=[]
               for index, attach in enumerate(message.attachments):
                    embed2.add_field(name=f"Attachment {index+1}", value=f"[{attach.filename}]({attach.url})")
                    attachmentFile = await attach.to_file()
                    attachmentFiles.append(attachmentFile)
               if not message.author.bot:     
                    await channel1.send(embed=embed, files=attachmentFiles)
                    await channel2.send(embed=embed, files=attachmentFiles)

At first, it worked as i wanted but when a minute or so goes code just breaks and always returns "False" and strangely, when I delete somebodys message and they delete their own another message just in time, my variable becomes "True" and two embeds will say message deleted by Me in reality i deleted only one message.

You can't get the user who deleted the message in the on_message_delete listener, you would have to use the Audit Logs for that. When the author deletes their own message, no audit log entry will be created. When another user deletes someone elses message, there will be an audit log. You can create another listener for these. API Reference: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=audit%20log#discord.on_audit_log_entry_create

I don't think you understood my issue. I know I can fetch any log with that listener, that is what i did up there (line 3-8). I absolutely knew that thing but there is a problem with this approach, when a message deleted by the same mod (and the author is the same) it doesn't create a new entry thus your advice (listener) won't trigger. My approach's problem is that I compare the creation date and now but when the scenario I mentioned happens, creation date doesn't updates to now but stays the same when the first message deleted.
